# How to create dragable three.js item in maptalks?

Tags: three.js, maps

I need to add three.js shape into maptalks add can drag it.

I can add three.js item in maptalks but can`t drag.

I used DragControls like this link:
https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/DragControls
that is worked without maptalks but when added maptalks to project DragControls not worked!

Comment: Could you show your attempts so far?